# onfinish on global soundmanager object

Tags: javascript, object, soundmanager2

I would like to launch a function at the end of my sound, this code works :

```
var mysound;

var next = function(){
 alert('end');   
};

soundManager.onready(function () {

    mysound = soundManager.createSound({
        id:'foo',
        url:'http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=2077&type=mp3'
    })
    mysound.play({onfinish:next});
    // change to this 
    // mysound.play();
 });
// in another .js
// mysound.onfinish(next) // doesn't work
// mysound.prototype.options.onfinish = next // doesn't work
```

I would like to do something like I comment.

[code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4L1t9xh/6/)

Comment: Remove `var` before `mysound` to make it global (same goes for `next`, probably)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that mysound tries to assign the onfinish before it's set to the correct value.

```
var mysound;

var next = function(){
 alert('end');   
};
function importedFromOtherFile( mysound ) {
  mySound.onfinish(next);
}

soundManager.onready(function () {

    mysound = soundManager.createSound({
        id:'foo',
        url:'http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=2077&type=mp3'
    })
    mysound.play({onfinish:next});
    // change to this 
    functionImportedFromOtherFile(mysound);
 });
```

if you want it to be in a different file, see if you can give it a call back or throw an even with mysound after it's set

Comment: I will try `soundManager.onready(function () {  mySound.onfinish(next);}`